# Added predictive value: valid approaches?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, risk

I am planning an analysis to quantify the effects of a new biomarker on cardiovascular risk in terms of added predictive value. Having read this nice post by @Frank Harrell:

https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/

it seems that one valid approach is to fit a model with the current risk factors (e.g. that are used in some version of the Framington risk score) and a second model parametrized the same as above but with the addition of the new biomarker. Then we can perform appropriate comparisons e.g. a likelihood ratio test, Brier score on bootstrapped data for honest assessment etc. However, I have also come across instances where instead of using known risk factors as explanatory variables (and hence estimating their parameters on the current data), the Framington risk score itself is fitted:

as a single explanatory variable e.g.: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24367001/

or as an offset e.g.: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26071658/

By fitting current risk factors separately as explanatory variables, we are estimating each coefficient on the current data, which will also likely change when we add the new biomarker in the second model. However, this does not happen when fitting the predicted risk from a current model such as the FRS as either an explanatory variable or offset. Since we are not re-estimating the coefficients of the known risk factors on the current data, this doesn't seem like a valid approach. I would greatly appreciate some thoughts on this.